# Ricci scalar in presence of torsion

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature

Many authors deriving the field equations for teleparallel gravity (TPG) move from the Riemann tensor for TPG:

$R^\rho{}_{\mu\lambda\nu} = - \nabla_\lambda K^\rho{}_{\mu\nu} + \nabla_\nu K^\rho{}_{\mu\lambda} - K^\rho{}_{\sigma\lambda} K^\sigma{}_{\mu\nu} + K^\rho{}_{\sigma\nu}K^{\sigma}{}_{\mu\lambda}$
where $K^\lambda{}_{\mu\nu}  = \frac{1}{2}(T_\mu{}^\lambda{}_\nu + T_{\nu}{}^{\lambda}{}_\mu - T^\lambda{}_{\mu\nu}) $

To the Ricci tensor:

$R_{\mu\nu} = - \nabla_\rho K^\rho{}_{\mu\nu} + \nabla_\nu K^\rho{}_{\mu\rho} - K^\rho{}_{\sigma\rho} K^\sigma{}_{\mu\nu} + K^\rho{}_{\sigma\nu}K^{\sigma}{}_{\mu\rho}$

To the Ricci scalar:

$R = -T+2\nabla^\mu T_\mu$ where $T = \frac{1}{2}T^\sigma{}_{\mu\nu}T_{\sigma}{}^{\mu\nu} + \frac{1}{4} T^\sigma{}_{\mu\nu}T^{\nu\mu}{}_\sigma - T_{\sigma_\mu}{}^\sigma T^{\nu\mu}{}_{\nu} $

(see, e.g., [Bahamonde, Bohmer, and Wright, Eq. 16](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.05120) or [Golovnev, Koivisto and Sandstad, Eq. 15](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.06271)).

I understand the contraction and move from the Riemann tensor to the Ricci tensor but am having trouble deriving the Ricci scalar. Here's what I have so far (and I'd appreciate any help!):

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
R = R_\mu{}^\mu & = - g^{\mu\nu}\nabla_\rho (T_\mu{}^\rho{}_{\nu} + T_\nu{}^\rho{}_{\mu} - T^\rho{}_{\mu\nu})+  g^{\mu\nu}\nabla_\nu(T_\mu{}^\rho{}_\rho + T_\rho{}^\rho{}_\mu -T^\rho{}_{\mu\rho} ) - g^{\mu\nu} K^\rho{}_{\sigma\rho} K^\sigma{}_{\mu\nu} + g^{\mu\nu} K^\rho{}_{\sigma\nu}K^{\sigma}{}_{\mu\rho}
\\& = - \nabla_\rho (T_\mu{}^\rho{}^{\mu} + T^{\mu\rho}{}_{\mu} - T^\rho{}_{\mu}{}^{\mu})+ \nabla^\mu(T_\mu{}^\rho{}_\rho + T_\rho{}^\rho{}_\mu -T^\rho{}_{\mu\rho} ) - K ^\rho{}_{\sigma\rho} K^\sigma{}_{\mu}{}^{\mu} + K^\rho{}_{\sigma}{}^{\mu}K^{\sigma}{}_{\mu\rho}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

where we've used the definition of contortion and metric compatibility to pull the metric inside the derivative operator. Often, $T^\mu$ is defined as: $T^\nu{}_{\nu}{}^{\mu}$ or $T_\mu$ is defined as $T^\nu{}_{\nu\mu}$ so using that and the anti-symmetry of the torsion tensor in its second and third index, we have:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
R = 2\nabla_\rho T^\rho - \nabla_\rho T^\rho{}_{\mu}{}^{\mu}+ \nabla^\mu T_\mu{}^\rho{}_\rho + 2 \nabla^\mu T_\mu - (2T_\sigma+T_\sigma{}^\rho{}_{\rho})(2T^\sigma-T^\sigma{}_{\mu}{}^\mu) + g^{\mu\nu} K^\rho{}_{\sigma\nu}K^{\sigma}{}_{\mu\rho}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

I presume the second and third term cancel one another since they only differ on their indices of contraction but I'm not sure how to simplify the rest?